# Dynamic ports on MSSQL for Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux

in MSSQL 2016 and 2017 on Windows, on the Server Configuration Manager you can change the setting to use dynamic ports. Is there a way to do the same in MSSQL 2017 for Linux?

Comment: U mean MySQL for Linux?

Comment: Seems MSSQL already support linux, so OP did not make wrong.

Comment: MsSQL \ SQL server for Linux. Dan's answer below is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2017 on Linux does not currently support named instances or the SQL Server Browser service needed to discover them so dynamic ports serves no purpose.

You can [specify a static port using the mssql-config tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#tcpport). Applications will need to specify that port number in the connection string if other than the default 1433 port.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer is helpful.

Comment: @EvghenTester, glad this information helped. If it answered your question, [mark this as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to help others with the same question easily find the solution.